# gles v2 newbie wants to draw a line

Tags: colors, line, vertices

i'm an old glBegin() programmer and i need to port this structure

struct Line { float color[3]; float vertices[2][3];};

to a more new drawing paradigm. 
how to draw this with glDrawArrays or glDrawElements, supposed that shaders are ok?

thank you, mic.

Answer (score 0):

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 3, lines->vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 3, lines->color);
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, line_indices);
```

Assuming you've assigned your vertex shader's 'position' and 'color' vertex attributes to 0 and 1. Indices array should be something like `GLshort indices[] = { 0, 1 };`.

Comment: i don't have indices, is it good to use glDrawArrays(GL_LINES,0,2)?

Comment: yes, it is completely ok to use DrawArrays as long as you don't want to rearrange indices

Comment: i was unsecure on how send the two array to the pipeline.

Comment: so doing glBindBuffer and glVertexAttribPointer for every array and so call glDrawArrays worked.                                                            sorry but my reputation here don't permite me to give you +1.

Comment: It's ok. Just note that you don't _have_ _to_ use `glBindBuffer` and pass actual array pointers instead of offset. For small objects such as lines it's very unlikely you'll see any performance penalty. Also, even if you use vertex buffers, you could put all your data into one buffer and just manipulate offset/stride - which is, in my view, better then having separate buffers for everything.

Comment: float axes[]={...}                                                          float axescol[]={...}

Comment: glGenBuffers(vertex_buffer)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, axis...
   
glGenBuffers(1, &index_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, axescol...

Comment: glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(position_slot...
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(color_slot...
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES,0,12);

Comment: Ough... Don't do that. If you want to extend question - edit it, don't post code in multiple subsequent comments.